# Do the free 30 day period and the 14/21 day trial add up in EVE Online?

Tags: eve-online

I'm looking at [EVE Online: Incarna at Steam](http://store.steampowered.com/app/8500/) right now. It says I get 30 days free (well, included in the game's price, really) and then I'll have to pay. It also says, that **the product key won't work with existing accounts**. I'd like to first get the trial (either the 14 days one from the official site or the 21 days one (I think it is based on an invite) that I saw mentioned at some forums) and decide if I like the game. Then I'd like to buy it on Steam. Do I get 44/51 days of play? Or does it mean that if I use the trial I am no longer entitled to the 30 days extra from the Steam title?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The game itself does not cost any money, you can [download the client](http://www.eveonline.com/download/) from the Eve Online homepage freely.

The price in Steam is exactly the same as the price you pay for the initial account setup and the first month of play when ordering directly from CCP (at least in my location). You don't get any benefit when buying from Steam.

A trial account is an existing account, and usually only one type of starting bonus can be attached to same account. Though I don't know it for sure, but I would not risk it and just get someone to send me an invite to get the 21 free days and then buy a subscription directly from CCP.

Comment: Steam price is 19,99 Euro, while the 1-month subscription fee is 14.95 Euro. I don't get it.

Comment: @Haze There is an additional 5 EUR account creation fee, so the total cost is the same no matter if you buy from Steam or CCP.

Comment: OK, that explains it.

Comment: It looks like by getting the trial and then simply activating the account I would get exactly the same deal while being sure that I get both the trial and the 30 day period (because it's paid for). Can I continue whatever career I start on the trial?

Comment: @Haze You can convert a trial account into a full account (keeping your characters) by buying the subscription from CCP, I did that very recently. I can't speak for what happens when you buy it from somewhere else.

Comment: That sums it up, I think. I don't need the Steam version, I just thought it was a convenient way of purchasing the game. Thanks.

Comment: Found additonal info at EVE forums:
http://www.eveonline.com/ingameboard.asp?a=topic&threadID=1513005
http://www.eveonline.com/ingameboard.asp?a=topic&threadID=1239170

Answer (score 2):

Yes they add up, I just tried.

I had the 21 day invitation trial, bought the game on Steam, added the key to the account, and got 30 more days.

[image: Code Activation Success]

[image: Transaction History]

Comment: Is this still valid? I read that you don't get any Key anymore.

Comment: @Streuner I've no clue, I'm no longer playing it, sorry

Comment: It's ok. I'm looking forward to start with this game and due to the forums this seems to be outdated, because steam creates a new account with your steam-login.